# Polymorphic lambda calculus

Tags: scala, lambda-calculus

In the very instructive talk [Constraints Liberate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqmsQeSzMdw), Rúnar says, there is exactly one way to implement a function with this signature:

```
def id[A](a: A): A
```

Well, obviously. But nitpicking people could come up with a implementation like

```
def id[A](a: A): A = {
  if (a.isInstanceOf[Integer])  
    5
  else 
    a
}
```

Ok, why do I care?

Exactly the same issue could be said about the functions in the famous [Theorems for free! article](https://www.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf), but there we have the restriction of `functions in the polymorphic lambda calculus`, and surely Type-Casing is invalid in this context.

I am looking for a precise way to make clear what subset of the Scala language is allowed when we say something like *"there is only one possible implementation of a pure function with this signature: "*

```
def id[A](a: A): A
```

Comment: Speaking of nitpicks, the return value for `id` should be `a`, not `A` :)

Comment: Nitpicking a little more, `if (a.isInstanceOf[Integer]) { 5 }` has absolute no effect in id. What you maybe want is `if (a.isInstanceOf[Integer]) { 5 } else a`.

Comment: Do you know what a "pure function" is?

Comment: @pedrofurla If you mean that `_.isInstanceOf[X]` is _not_ a pure function, I disagree. I see no side effects, and the output is entirely determined by the input. In particular, if you're telling me that `_.isInstanceOf[X]` is not a pure function, then `_ == _` isn't pure anymore either.

Comment: Nope, didn't mean that. Do you know what total functions are?

Comment: @pedrofurla, for what it's worth `_.isInstanceOf` is total, as is OP's modified `id` function.

Comment: And who said it isn't?

Comment: @pedrofurla: Whats your point?

Answer (score 4):

The glib answer is "the subset of Scala modeled by the polymorphic lambda calculus" :).

Less glibly the [the Scalazzi Safe Scala subset](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7810909/talks/parametricity/4985cb8e6d8d9a24e32d98204526c8e3b9319e33/parametricity.pdf) has a pretty good list of conditions. They're reproduced below with minor modifications.

- No `null`
- No exceptions
- No type casing (`_.isInstanceOf` and `case` matches), except for one exception
- No type casting (`_.asInstanceOf`)
- No side effects
- No `.equals` (`_ == _`), `.toString`, or `.hashCode`
- No `notify` or `wait` (which I would lump with side effects)
- No `classOf` or `.getClass`
- No general recursion (more generally all functions must be total)

The one exception to "No type casing" is [pattern matching with `match ... case` on the equivalent of algebraic data types with `sealed` hierarchies and case classes and case objects](http://typelevel.org/blog/2014/11/10/why_is_adt_pattern_matching_allowed.html). To know if your particular `match ... case` statement is allowed, use the following rules:

- Only use extractors in the `case` statement; do not use `case (x: Int)...` type matches. Make sure your extractors obey the Scalazzi rules (the easiest way to fulfill this is to not write the extractors at all, i.e. only use compiler-provided extractors in the form of `case class` and `case object`).
- The match must cover all possible cases. This implies no `match is not exhaustive` warnings and that the thing you're matching against better be a subtype of something `sealed`.

Those rules are slightly different than the `fold`-encoding rule that the Typelevel blog article proposes, but are basically equivalent (the rules above are more conservative and hopefully easier to keep in your head).

If you can't/don't want to verify that these hold for all the functions you didn't write but use, I've found that following the rules above for your own code and then not depending on functions that take in `Any` as an argument or produce `Unit` as a return type is often enough.

Comment: Your points are a useful guide from a practical point of view, thank you. However, I am really interested in the theoretical aspect of this question. @jörg-w-mittag`s comment goes in this direction. Ruling out reflection as effectful leads to the question of an exact definition of `reflective` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is correct, and does not require subsetting as such, if you restrict your attention to referentially transparent functions.

Comment: Wouldn't restricting be a kind of "subsetting"?

Comment: Mutable state and I/O are the obvious offenders. One not-so-obvious side-effect that must be disallowed as well, is reflection. A couple of years ago, Erik Meijer has given a nice example of how to implement mutable state using threading, so that has to be disallowed as well. (Side-effects really are nasty. If you allow one, you get them all!)

Comment: @jörg-w-mittag: I think you are refering to this [article](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2611829). Thank you very much, this reads very interesting. The question *What are effectful expressions in Scala?* seems to be quite complex if even object creation is considered effectfull...

Comment: @KlausSchulz: Actually, it was a video-taped whiteboarding session on Channel9, but the example he gave was the same Cω example from the paper you dug up. This was in response to frequent comments on the Channel9 discussion forums that Microsoft could "make C♯ more powerful by removing mutable state", and Erik's argument was two-fold: a) you cannot make a language more powerful by *removing* something, and b) merely removing mutable state won't help, because you can emulate mutable state with threading. (Or, in other words: not only will removing mutable state from C♯ not make it more …

Comment: … powerful, it also will not make it *less* powerful, in fact, it will have no effect at all!)